# $\sum a_{n}$ converges but $\sum a_{n}^2 $ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have to give an example of a convergent series $\sum a_{n}$ for which $\sum a_{n}^2 $ diverges.

I think that such a series cannot exist because if $\sum a_{n}$ converges absolutely then $\sum a_{n}^2 $ will always converge right?

Comment: The implication you said after "because" is true but it's still possible that $\sum_n a_n$ converges but not absolutely and $\sum_n a_n^2$ does not converge (absolutely nor by any means).

Comment: @max_zorn That's if $\sum a_n$ converges **absolutely**.

Comment: Yes, you are right Robert, sorry!

Answer (score 15):

The alternating series test gives a wealth of examples. Take
$$
a_n=(-1)^n/\sqrt{n}
$$
for example.

Comment: You beat me to it by $14$ seconds.

Comment: Are there any that don't involve a $(-1)^n$ term?

Comment: @Ingolifs: $\sin$. But if the sequence is non-negative, it is a basic exercise to prove that the implication holds.

Answer (score 10):

Try $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Answer (score 4):

More generally,
if $a_n = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/(2m)}}$,
then
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n
$
converges for integer $m \ge 0$
and
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^{2m}
$
diverges.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example I have in mind is : 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} $$

Beware that convergent (CV) and absolutely convergent (ACV) can be very different. 
Indeed, if $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n $ is ACV then, $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n^2$ is also ACV. To prove it, you can simply notice that, since $\lim a_n=0$ then for $n$ big enough, $|a_n^2|<|a_n|$.

You can also ask yourself a more general question : 
What are the function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that for all 
$\sum a_n$ CV (resp. ACV), $\sum f(a_n)$ is CV (resp. ACV).

It is a (difficult) exercise to show that for $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$,

$$\sum a_n ~CV \Rightarrow \sum f(a_n) ~CV \quad \text{iff} \quad \exists \eta>0,\exists \lambda\in \mathbb R,\forall x\in ]-\eta,\eta[, \quad f(x)=\lambda x $$

$$\sum a_n ~CV \Rightarrow \sum f(a_n) ~ACV \quad \text{iff} \quad \exists \eta>0,\forall x\in ]-\eta,\eta[, \quad f(x)=0 \quad\quad\quad~~$$

$$\sum a_n ~ACV \Rightarrow \sum f(a_n) ~ACV \quad \text{iff} \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$$ $$\quad f(0)=0 \text{ and }\exists \eta>0,\exists M >0,\forall x\in ]-\eta,\eta[, |f(x)|\leq M |x| $$

$$\sum a_n ACV \Rightarrow \sum f(a_n) ~CV \quad \text{iff} \quad \sum a_n ~ACV \Rightarrow \sum f(a_n) ~ACV~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ $$

Comment: $\sum_n a_n^2$ converges for this one.

Comment: oups I answer too fast ^^

Comment: Can you correct it?  Want to upvote the distinction between ACV and CV but can't bring myself to do it with the error

Comment: corrected, I also added a more general statement.

Comment: I have a PhD in math and my eyes glaze over when reading this post because of the unnecessary jumble of symbols. Words are generally preferable for longer statements.

Comment: While I realize it's a standard notation, $x\in]-\eta,\eta[$ just looks so horrible--the unbalanced brackets make it hard to parse. $x\in(-\eta,\eta)$ is much better, though $|x| < \eta$ is better than both.

Comment: I'm in agreement with the comment by Matt above, for me it's almost unreadable (in the sense that it takes way too much effort to parse it). A (IMO) better way of presenting the first statement would be something like "If $\sum a_n$ converges then $\sum f(a_n)$ converges if $f(x)$ is proportional to $x$ in a neighborhood of $x=0$."

Comment: @MattSamuel I agree on the first part, not on the second. This writing is way more efficient than english sentences when you're used to it. Part of the problem here comes from the care I didn't put into better layout.

Comment: @eyeballfrog the use of parenthesis instead of brackets is an anglosaxon idiosyncrasy that leads to the use of parenthesis everywhere which is not clearer. However,  writing $x\in\,]-\eta,\eta[$ instead of $x\in ]-\eta,\eta[$ is slighly better.